# Facebook JavaScript SDK: run something after all the queries are returned

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to count friends' gender with Facebook JavaScript API.  The problem is FB SDK is based on async call so I cannot fire an action **after all the queries are done**.

For example, here is code to count how many male/female friends I have.  But the last line won't work as it can get executed while FB.api() is still running.

What's the best way to handle this?

```
FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
    if(response.data) {
        var genderCount = {};

        $.each(response.data, function(index, friend) {
            FB.api('/' + friend.id, function(frienddata) {
                if (frienddata.gender) {
                    if (genderCount[frienddata.gender]) {
                        genderCount[frienddata.gender]++;
                    }
                    else {
                        genderCount[frienddata.gender]=1;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
});

// later do something with genderCount

alert('I have ' + genderCount['male'] + ' male friends'); // won't work
```

Comment: Use a counter for the number of queries that have finished, and call a function that checks this counter in the callback of each query, after incrementing said counter. Counter reaches number of queries == callback function does something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you probably want to use a more efficient `fql` query, such as

```
SELECT name, sex, uid 
FROM user 
WHERE uid in (
  SELECT uid2 
  FROM friend 
  WHERE uid1 = me()
)
```

Simply pass this to `graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20%name....`

Then, move the alert into the response handler, after you have completed summing up the numbers.

```
FB.api('/fql', 
  {q: "SELECT name, sex, uid FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())"}, 
  function (response) {
    if (response.data) {
        var genderCount = {
            male: 0,
            female: 0,
            unknown: 0
        };
        response.data.forEach(function (row) {
            genderCount[row.sex || 'unknown']++;
        });
        alert(JSON.stringify(genderCount));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.api('/me/friends', function(response)
{
if(response.data) 
{
    var genderCount = {};
    var i = 0;
    function GetGender(friend_id)
    {
        FB.api('/' + friend_id, function(frienddata) 
        {
            if (frienddata.gender) 
            {
                if (genderCount[frienddata.gender]) 
                {
                    genderCount[frienddata.gender]++;
                }
                else 
                {
                    genderCount[frienddata.gender]=1;
                }
            }

            if(i == response.data.length - 1)
            {
                Results(genderCount);
            }
            else
            {
                GetGender(response.data[++i].id);
            }
        });
    }

    GetGender(response.data[i].id);
}
});


function Results(genderCount)
{
// here you are after all the calls
}
```

Comment: Generally it is good to give some description about what you've done here and why it is the answer.